# Integrate OpenCV into Xcode using Swift Language

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv

I try to integrate OpenCV into Xcode by following this tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywUBHqxwM5Q

edit: I have tried more tutorials and always see those type of warnings.

However, I found a lot of warning after doing this. I have solved some of them but there is still a big chunk of warnings.

The warning is called

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Warning Group:

direct access in function '___cxx_global_var_init' from 
file '/Users/user/Desktop/OpenCV-SwiftTest/OpenCV-
SwiftTest/opencv2.framework/opencv2(flann.o)' to global weak symbol 
'guard variable for 
cvflann::anyimpl::SinglePolicy<cvflann::anyimpl::empty_any>::policy' 
from file 
'/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OpenCV-
SwiftTest-awmplbufjrmhqrbptnqhlxqxvptp/Build/Intermediates/OpenCV-
SwiftTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OpenCV-SwiftTest.build/Objects-
normal/x86_64/OpenCVWrapper.o' means the weak symbol cannot be 
overridden at runtime.
This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled 
with different visibility settings.
```

I found some related answers such as

```
  1.Symbols Hidden by Default
  2.Inline Methods Hidden
```

Since the tutorial only includes OpenCV for one project and I have checked its setting with the above requirement.

It just a simple project where is the different translation units?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift cannot work with C++ directly, so you need to use at a minimum Objective C wrappers to communicate with OpenCV.

For example, I have the following method in my C++ class:

```
cv::Mat crop(const cv::Mat &src, cv::Rect2f &rect);
```

I then have an Objective-C method that exists in an Objective-C++ files (this means the filename in XCode has a second m (ex: MyWrapper.mm).

The function to call this in Obj-C would look something like this:

```
- (void)crop:(nonnull UIImage *)source
        rect:(CGRect)rect
completionHandler:(nonnull ImageCompletionHandler)completionHandler {
    MAT src = [Conversion cvMatWithImage:source];
    RECT_2F rect_2f = [Conversion cvRectFromRect:rect];
    MAT dst = self.basicPtr->crop(src, rect_2f);

    completionHandler([Conversion imageFromCVMat:dst]);
}
```

1. The first Conversion call converts a `UIImage` into a Mat for OpenCV to process
2. The second Conversion call converts a `CGRect` into a `cv::Rect2f`
3. The self.basicPts->crop(src, rect_2f) function is using a pointer to my class to access the crop function above
4. Finally, I have a closure that takes the Mat object OpenCV gives me and converts it into a `UIImage` for iOS to work with

Then, back in Swift land, you need to first have a bridging header for the Objective-C wrapper so that Swift can access it.

Once you have that, then calling the function is trivial:

```
func crop(with image: UIImage, rect: CGRect) {
    let wrapper = BasicWrapper()
    wrapper.crop(image, rect: rect) { (image) in
        // Handle image
    }
}
```

It took a lot of work to fill in all those pieces, but if you look around here, you can find all the pieces you need (I know I did).